# Create Json from a view

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to create a json from Views, using [Views Datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource).

The problem is that if I create a display "page", using Json as style, if I try to go to www.mysite.com/path/to/page the system doesn't return me the Json (as I see in the preview of the view) but an entire classic drupal page with the output of the json in the content region (so I've menus, regions, etc).

Is there a way to obtain the output as a simple json?

Comment: Ok, the answer is here: http://drupal.org/node/1778568#comment-6631208 I have to disable "Views API mode"

Comment: +1 You can answer your own question, not just comment. You should add that the 'Views API mode' is a setting in the Settings under Format section when editing the View. You'd get an upvote from me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way is to *uncheck* the "Views API" flag in display settings.